# Why is typed JSON parsing in C# SO MUCH slower than node.js JSON.parse?

Tags: c#, node.js, json, .net-core, benchmarking

I have one simple JSON object in a string and I'm comparing the ellapsed time of parsing (deserializing) the object between C# (.NET core) and Node.js

Node.js test:

```
const { performance } = require('perf_hooks');

const data = '{"_id":"5ff0fa604a1956d24e936b15","index":0,"guid":"de606748-9b6f-473c-bef4-efce5cd2914d","isActive":true,"balance":"$1,475.89","picture":"http://placehold.it/32x32","age":33,"eyeColor":"green","name":"Clara Mcmahon","gender":"female","company":"QUILM","email":"claramcmahon@quilm.com","phone":"+1 (871) 509-3806","address":"391 Schroeders Avenue, Ironton, Hawaii, 1368","about":"Commodo aliqua Lorem adipisicing esse in deserunt incididunt quis. Commodo sint amet quis adipisicing exercitation non Lorem aliquip tempor velit incididunt laboris. Ullamco in id anim commodo incididunt sint ad amet.\\r\\n","registered":"2014-05-23T05:47:53 -02:00","latitude":78.629772,"longitude":10.274508}';
let t0 = performance.now()
let parsed = JSON.parse(data); // measuring this part
let t1 = performance.now()
console.log(t1-t0);
```

C# test:

```
string data = "{\"_id\":\"5ff0fa604a1956d24e936b15\",\"index\":0,\"guid\":\"de606748-9b6f-473c-bef4-efce5cd2914d\",\"isActive\":true,\"balance\":\"$1,475.89\",\"picture\":\"http://placehold.it/32x32\",\"age\":33,\"eyeColor\":\"green\",\"name\":\"Clara Mcmahon\",\"gender\":\"female\",\"company\":\"QUILM\",\"email\":\"claramcmahon@quilm.com\",\"phone\":\"+1 (871) 509-3806\",\"address\":\"391 Schroeders Avenue, Ironton, Hawaii, 1368\",\"about\":\"Commodo aliqua Lorem adipisicing esse in deserunt incididunt quis. Commodo sint amet quis adipisicing exercitation non Lorem aliquip tempor velit incididunt laboris. Ullamco in id anim commodo incididunt sint ad amet.\\r\\n\",\"registered\":\"2014-05-23T05:47:53 -02:00\",\"latitude\":78.629772,\"longitude\":10.274508}";
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();
Person person = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Person>(data); // measuring this part
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

//...

public class Person
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public int index { get; set; }
    public string guid { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
    public string balance { get; set; }
    public string picture { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string eyeColor { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string about { get; set; }
    public string registered { get; set; }
    public float latitude { get; set; }
    public float longtitude { get; set; }
}
```

### **The results:**

**Node.js** *(v14.15.3)* returns `0.0380ms` on average

**C#** *(.NET core, net5.0, Release)* returns `40ms` on average

### **The question:**

Why is C#'s **TYPED** JSON parsing performing such badly against node.js's **dynamic** JSON parsing?

Am I measuring this badly? Why is this happening?

*P.S.: I'm building an app that listens for websockets and parses one JSON object in each websocket (with span of a couple of seconds), so that's why I'm benchmarking only one JSON object.*

Comment: Is every run with a warm cache or cold cache? (Do you restart the whole app each time?)

Comment: Mozilla says the following for `performance.now`:  It's important to keep in mind that to mitigate potential security threats such as Spectre, browsers typically round the returned value by some amount in order to be less predictable. This inherently introduces a degree of inaccuracy by limiting the resolution or precision of the timer. For example, Firefox rounds the returned time to 1 millisecond increments.

Comment: StopWatch is not really a benchmarking tool, unless you are warning this method up which will make sure al the dependencies are loaded and running this test in release then you are not getting a very accurate picture at all. Also you are comparing 2 very different things.

Comment: `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` does more than just parse JSON: it needs to convert the parsed values and then assign them to the properties of the deserialized object. This uses reflection, and is inherently slow. `JSON.parse` just dumps everything in a map. In other words, you're not comparing the same things. The closest equivalent in .NET would probably be `JsonDocument.Parse`.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel By default JsonConvert uses dynamic code generation, which once warmed up is very fast

Comment: @Charlieface This looks like `System.Text.Json`, not Newtonsoft.

Comment: If I run your code I get about the same results. however, if i run it again straight away and make sure its different data, I get 0 milliseconds. If i run this code in BenchmarkDotNet, which is an actual benchmark tool I get about 2.4 μs (microseconds)

Comment: Anyway, voting to close as not reproducible.

Comment: Its not even the same thing. You're parsing and then casting to a class. If you want to compare them. Then just parse the string into a jobject and stop there.

Comment: your test it not right

Comment: @Charlieface I restart the app (program) every time.

Comment: @00110001 I tried parsing it twice with different data just like you did and I get the same results just like you (0ms on the 2nd run). So yeah it just needs to be "warmed up"

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Thank you for your suggestion! I'll actually be using `JsonDocument.Parse` because I need more flexibility (and it'll be even maybe faster?)

Answer (score 0):

During the first call to deserialize. System.Text.Json needs to generate a cache to map JSON to class.

Subsequent calls will be much faster.

Node.js does not need that as it does not map it to class or check types.

If you want an apple-to-apple comparison, you should use Deserialize not to a class but to JsonElement, which is also unstructured.

PS: If you want accurate benchmarks, you should run your call in a loop lots of times to have reliable results.